# Angular 1.5 component doesn't call parent controller method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I'm using angular 1.5 component and I want to call controller's method which is bind to scope from component's method call. Please find below code

```
<table-pagination previous="getPageName()"></table-pagination>

bindings: {
   previous:"&"
}

this.previous = function () { };
```

In above example, I want to call **getPageName()** method of controller which is bind to $scope , here I am not using **controllerAs** syntax.

Comment: Call from your component?
Try using "<" binding and running it using this.previous() from your component's controller.

Comment: from component you should call `$ctrl.previous()`